# Microsoft Sync Framework through USB between Windows CE Device and Windows PC

Tags: windows, usb, windows-ce, synchronization, rapi

How can we use the MS Sync Framework to synchronize a text file located on a Windows CE 6.0 device with a text file located on a Windows PC when the device and the PC are connected through USB?

We already know how to do this when...

- the two target text files are on the same PC,
- the device and the PC are connected through Ethernet, or
- the device and the PC are connected through Internet.

We have a current hack that uses the Remote APi. It is as follows:

1. The user connects the device cradle to the PC using USB.
2. The user docks the device in its cradle.
3. The user opens the desktop app on the PC.
4. The user clicks the sync button in the desktop app.
5. The desktop app then uses the Remote API (RAPI2) to copy the text file from the device to the PC.
6. The desktop app next uses the MS Sync framework to sync the two files.
7. The desktop app finally uses RAPI2 to copy the synced text file back to the device.

We would like to eliminate steps 5 and 7 by doing the sync across the USB cable. Is this possible?

We want to eliminate steps 5 and 7 because, as the target text file becomes large, the copying of the text file between the device and the PC could be time intensive, thus, the user experience would suffer.

We suspect that we might have to create a driver to eliminate steps 5 and 7. Is that true? If not, what other approaches could we take? For instance, could we somehow expose a WCF endpoint across USB?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the OS image you can replace the active sync protocol with RNDIS. In this way the USB connection will be managed as a LAN connection on both sides and your software that works on a regular network should work in the same way.